# why to add the interaction of two fixed effects in regression

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

A general question raised during my study.

For example, we are estimating the effect of X on Y at individual level. Then it is intuitive for me to add state fixed effect and year fixed effect in the regression.

$Y_{it} = X_{it} + \mu_{s} + \mu_{t} + \epsilon_{it}$

While in a lot of papers, people also add the interaction of the two fixet effects. The specification then looks like

$Y_{it} = X_{it} + \mu_{s} + \mu_{t} + \mu_{st} + \epsilon_{it}$

My question is that why people do so?
WHat variation is exactly captured by the interaction of the fixed effect?

Thank you a lot in advance!